# C++/CLI stored procedure can't find resources

Tags: c++, sql-server, command-line-interface

I have some code which is fine in C++/CLI console application.

```
unsigned char* res2buffer()
{
  HMODULE HInstance = 0x00;
  try
  {
    HRSRC hrsrc = ::FindResourceW( HInstance, L"IDR_1251", RT_RCDATA);

    if( hrsrc == NULL)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    const size_t nsize = ::SizeofResource( HInstance, hrsrc );

    HGLOBAL hglob = ::LoadResource( HInstance, hrsrc );

    LPVOID rdata = LockResource(hglob);
    fuzzyRus = new unsigned char[ nsize ];

    ::memcpy( fuzzyRus, rdata, nsize );

    UnlockResource(hglob);

    ::FreeResource(hglob);

    return fuzzyRus;
    }
    catch(...)
    {   
    }
    return nullptr;
 }
```

But is does not work in code made as Stored Procedure. Any clue? I guess I have to pass HInstance as a number is different then 0x00. The question is "Instance of what?"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `HMODULE` for your DLL like this:

```
HMODULE HInstance = NULL;

GetModuleHandleEx(
    GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS
    | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT,
    (LPCTSTR)res2buffer,
    &HInstance
);
```

Comment: Thanks but I found in more correct way the only problem I do not know how to find length of the resource

Answer (score 0):

Make solution in managed way:  File must be attached in linker option ***Input->Embeded Managed Resource File->***  resource\rustbl.bin

```
static const unsigned char*  GetRusTables() // get data from the resource file
{  
    Reflection::Assembly^ ca = Reflection::Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();

    IO::BinaryReader^ rusres = gcnew IO::BinaryReader( ca->GetManifestResourceStream( "rustbl.bin" ) ); 

    array<unsigned char>^   buffPtr  = rusres->ReadBytes( 413032 );
    pin_ptr<unsigned char>  fuzzyRus = &buffPtr[0];

    return fuzzyRus;     
}
```